# Android LocationManager and it's updates

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Can someone tell me, what is the best way to deal with situations when there is no GPS signal or from some reason fix cannot be acquired?

The thing is that I thought that it would be sufficient just to use onStatusChanged method from LocationListener, but when there is no GPS signal it never calls this method. Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my solution [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655). If there's no GPS fix it will use update from Network provider. If there are no updates at all it will us last known value.